# jquery issues when changing active navigation class on scroll and on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I'm doing a single page where navigation .active class should change both on scroll and on click. I'm also changing class of header when scrolling down (".large" and ".small"), but this two scripts somehow don't work with each other.

For header resizing I'm doing this:

```
$(document).on("scroll",function(){
if($(document).scrollTop()>200){
    $('header').removeClass('large').addClass('small');
} else{
    $('header').removeClass('small').addClass('large');

}
```

});

For change active class I'm doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

//smoothscroll
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off("scroll");

    $('a').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var target = this.hash,
        menu = target;
    $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
    }, 500, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });
});
});

function onScroll(event){
var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
$('#top-menu a').each(function () {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.
    position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $('#top-menu ul li a').removeClass("active");
        currLink.addClass("active");
    }
    else{
        currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

}

This works perfectly when scrolling, but clicking on a top nav link just crashes "header" function and it doesn't resize anymore. Can anyone see what's the problem is?

Comment: Try to fire the crollTop animation against the document element instead of `'html, body'`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

As f00bar mentioned, $(document).off("scroll"); removes the eventhandler. The scroll event wont be fired anymore. so your top code wont run after a click.